# Differing behaviours with EDITOR=emacsclient between git and sudoedit

Tags: emacsclient, sudo

In my `.profile` I've

```
export EDITOR="emacsclient -qa \"emacs --no-window-system --no-desktop\""
```

Doing `sudo -e /somefile` doesn't work even when Emacs server is running.  I get

```
emacsclient: unrecognized option '--no-window-system'
Try 'emacsclient --help' for more information
sudo: /somefile unchanged
```

However, `git commit` does the right thing (Emacs editor for writing up my commit message) with both Emacs server running and not (opens inside terminal).

```
export EDITOR="emacsclient -qa nano"
```

Now `sudo -e` is happy.  So it looks like `git` is OK with the spaces in the `-a` (alternate editor) option's argument while `sudo` is not.  But, shouldn't this be a  `emacsclient` problem?  Why do I see these different behaviours.

Comment: My guess is that `EDITOR` is a variable (ab)used by different programs differently. It's not because of `emacsclient` itself.